# 'ListViewItem' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to fill a listView with items from a access database.  I am able to complete this in a windows form but I am trying to do this in WPF. I am getting an error in my 'populate' function.  The Line 'ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);' is where I am seeing the error.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

```
        private void populate(String id, String emp, String basket, String recipe, String time, String pos1, String pos2, String pos3, String pos4, String pos5,
                          String pos6, String pos7, String pos8, String pos9, String pos10, String pos11, String pos12, String pos13, String pos14, String pos15, String pos16,
                          String pos17, String pos18, String pos19, String pos20, String pos21, String pos22, String pos23, String pos24, String pos25)
    {

        // Row           
            String[] row = { id.ToString(), emp.ToString(), basket.ToString(), recipe.ToString(), time.ToString(), pos1.ToString(), pos2.ToString(), pos3.ToString(), pos4.ToString(), pos5.ToString(), pos6.ToString(), pos7.ToString(), pos8.ToString(), pos9.ToString(), pos10.ToString(), pos11.ToString(), pos12.ToString(), pos13.ToString(), pos14.ToString(), pos15.ToString(), pos16.ToString(), pos17.ToString(), pos18.ToString(),
                         pos19.ToString(), pos20.ToString(), pos21.ToString(), pos22.ToString(), pos23.ToString(), pos24.ToString(), pos25.ToString() };

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
            listView.Items.Add(row);


    }


    // Retrieve 
    private void retrieve()
    {
        listView.Items.Clear();

        //Sql statement
        String sql = "Select * FROM Cleaner_Log";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

        //Open connection, retrieve, and fill listview1
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            adapter.Fill(dt);

            //Loop thru dt
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                populate(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), row[4].ToString(), row[5].ToString(), row[6].ToString(), row[7].ToString(), row[8].ToString(),
                         row[9].ToString(), row[10].ToString(), row[11].ToString(), row[12].ToString(), row[13].ToString(), row[14].ToString(), row[15].ToString(), row[16].ToString(), row[17].ToString(),
                         row[18].ToString(), row[19].ToString(), row[20].ToString(), row[21].ToString(), row[22].ToString(), row[23].ToString(), row[24].ToString(), row[25].ToString(), row[26].ToString(),
                         row[27].ToString(), row[28].ToString(), row[29].ToString());
            }

            con.Close();

            //Clear datatable
            dt.Rows.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a DataGrid? Otherwise see the online documentation of the ListView class for how to set its View to a GridView and declare GridViewColumns with bindings to the properties of a row item class. This may also be helpful: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/

Comment: hey Mike, let me know if the answer helped resolved issue, if not let me know how we can help

Answer (score 1):

> Constructor of ListView Class is a default Constructor and therefore
>   you cannot pass any arguments

**CodeBehind**

**Method Call Order**

```
public static System.Windows.Controls.ListView lv;
public static GridView gridView;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetupListView();//To Initializes List and its properties 
    SetupListViewHeaders();//adds Column headers
    Final();//Adding listview to Children for display
}
```

**Method Definition(s)**

```
private void SetupListView()
{
 lv = new System.Windows.Controls.ListView();            
 lv.Margin = new Thickness(10, 15, 0, 0);
 lv.Height = 500;
 lv.Width = 700;         
 gridView = new GridView();
 lv.View = gridView;           
}
```

```
private void SetupListViewHeaders()
{
    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
    {
                    Header = "Id",
                    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Id")
    });
    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
    {
        Header = "Emp",
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Emp")
    });
    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
    {
        Header = "Basket",
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Basket")
    });
    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
    {
        Header = "Recipe",
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Recipe")
    });
    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
    {
        Header = "Time",
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Time")
    });

    for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = "Pos" + i.ToString(),
            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Pos" + i.ToString())
        });
    }
}
```

```
private void Populate(String id, String emp, String basket, String recipe, String time, String pos1, String pos2, String pos3, String pos4, String pos5,
                             String pos6, String pos7, String pos8, String pos9, String pos10, String pos11, String pos12, String pos13, String pos14, String pos15, String pos16,
                             String pos17, String pos18, String pos19, String pos20, String pos21, String pos22, String pos23, String pos24, String pos25)
{ 

    lv.Items.Add(
    new
    {
        Id = 1, Emp = "David", Basket = basket, Recipe = recipe,
        Time = time, Pos1=pos1, Pos2=pos2, Pos3=pos3, Pos4=pos4, Pos5=pos5, Pos6=pos6, Pos7=pos7,Pos8=pos8,
        Pos9=pos9, Pos10=pos10, Pos11=pos11, Pos12=pos12, Pos13=pos13, Pos14=pos14, Pos15=pos15, Pos16=pos16,Pos17=pos17, Pos18=pos18,
        Pos19=pos19, Pos20=pos20, Pos21=pos21, Pos22=pos22, Pos23=pos23, Pos24=pos24, Pos25=pos25


    });


}
```

```
    private void Final()
    {
        MainGrid.Children.Add(lv);
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Note the word "row". What you are showing here populates a ListView with the items that OP wants to have in a single row of a ListView with multiple rows.

Comment: hmm, I dont see OP having mentioned that.

Comment: It's obvious if you carefully read the question. They are trying to assign a `row` array to the ListBoxItem constructor. All elements of the array should obviously be shown in a ListView/GridView row. And the populate method is executed in a loop over all rows.

Comment: Correct.  I am trying to pass 'row' into the listView.  I have a retrieve function that populates the row into the listView.

Comment: ahh okay I see, let me see what I can do. thanks for clarifying

Comment: Going to test.  I will provide feedback once complete.  Thank you

Comment: @MikePeezy, it would be great if you can give a feedback on this post. Cheers !!